# CH340G chip drivers intalation: *** [default] Error 2

Tags: drivers

I'm trying to install the Linux version drivers for the CH340G chip.
The make command for installing the drivers is returning the following error:

```
$ sudo make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.0-63-generic/build  M=/home/murilold/Dropbox/Projeto - Controlador de Temperatura/NodeMCU/Drivers/CH341SER_LINUX  
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-63-generic'
    arch/x86/Makefile:148: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
    Makefile:693: Cannot use CONFIG_CC_STACKPROTECTOR_STRONG: -fstack-protector-strong not supported by compiler
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Controlador'.  Pare.
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-63-generic'
    Makefile:5: recipe for target 'default' failed
    make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Does anyone know whats happening?

Comment: The error is likely due to the spaces in your directory name `Projeto - Controlador de Temperatura`

Comment: Thanks so much!!
Changed the directory name and it worked. Dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of spaces in my directory' name.

Reference: [bug #712: GNU make can't handle spaces in pathnames](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?712)